# Zend Framework with subdomains

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, apache2, subdomain, vhosts

Im having a problem getting zend framework to play nicely with subdomains on my server.  I have a LAMP stack running on ubuntu 11.10, I am also using a dynamic dns service where I have my zone records defined.  So basically my dns is setup like:

**DNS**:
Registered with one company and point my domain name to the Dynamic DNS's nameservers here.

With the Dynamic DNS host I have 3 defined zone records of type A:

```
mydomain.com 000.00.0.0
www.mydomain.com 000.00.0.0
*.mydomain.com 000.00.0.0  <-- wildcard to catch all subdomains
```

**Apache setup**:

in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` :: /sites-enabled
I have my default setup for `mydomain` and another vhost for `mysubdomain.mydomain.com`

`/var/www` :
I have mydomain.com/public /var/www/public folder as its document root

`/var/www/mysubdomain` :
I have `mysubdomain.mydomain.com` using `/var/www/mysubdomain/public` folder as its root

I think all of this is setup correctly because I serve any request to `www.mydomain.com` correctly, and I also serve any request to `www.mysubdomain.mydomain.com` correctly.

BUT when I make a request like `www.mysubdomain.mydomain.com/:controller` or `www.mysubdomain.mydomain.com/:controller/:action` I am issued a 404 Not Found from the server with the following message:

`The requested URL /controller/action was not found on this server.`

Im thinking this is an issue with my .htaccess which is setup the following way in

**my .htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

The thing is that when the application that I am currently trying to access is setup and accessd as a normal domain like `www.mysubdomain.com` everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Maybe you could try and provide the results.

Comment: Getting a 500 Internal server error with that .htaccess which is weird because if I remember correctly that is the default recommended .htaccess for zf

Comment: Can you place a test.php with just <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it in the /public folder and see if you can access it? Or are you also getting a 500 for that one?

Comment: Have you set `AllowOverride FileInfo` for your vhost in the httpd.conf? This is required to give .htaccess files permission to enable the rewrite engine.

Comment: Sorry, found my error. This was a new install of apache I i had to run a2enmod rewrite to enable url rewriting.  While my original .htaccess still works I gave Goeran the answer for taking the time.